# How to keep assistive touch always active on an Apple Watch?

Tags: apple-watch, accessibility, watchos

I'm using my Apple Watch to navigate my slides with hand gestures. I've set the return-to-clock feature to 1 hour and also disabled the sleep on wrist-down feature. However, the AssistiveTouch lasts for only a few seconds. I have to reactivate it by double-clenching.

I don't want to reactivate it repeatedly to use the gestures.

Is there a way to keep the hand gesture AssistiveTouch always active?